# The "caption" package adds a white space below the floats - How to remove it?

Tags: spacing, captions, vertical-spacing

I noticed that with the `caption` package loaded, the vertical space separating an `h`-float with the text is not the same above and below the figure.

Here are the (approximate) measurements I made:
[image]
[image]

With or without `caption`, the vertical space above the float is about 0.42 cm.
Without `caption`, the vertical space below the float is 0.46 cm (I suppose that the 0.04 cm difference comes from the fact that the caption has low letters (p, q, j, ...).
On the other hand, with the `caption` package loaded, the vertical space below the float increases to 0.51 cm.

What is the reason for the extra vertical space? How do you remove it (keeping `\belowcaptionskip=0pt`)? I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe, graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}

\setlength\intextsep{10pt}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{0pt}

\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy  dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over \rule{2em}{\baselineskip} the lazy dog.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{The quick brown fox \rule{2em}{\baselineskip} jumps over the lazy dog.}%
\end{figure}

The quick brown fox jumps over the \rule{2em}{\baselineskip} lazy  dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{The quick brown fox \rule{2em}{\baselineskip} jumps over the lazy dog.}%
\end{figure}

The quick brown fox jumps over the \rule{2em}{\baselineskip} lazy  dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

\end{document}
```

Comment: it is controlled by three skip lengths: `\floatsep`, `\textfloatsep` and `\intextsep`. The first determines a gap between consecutive floats inside an area dedicated for dloats; either top or a bottom part of a page. Then, the middle one controls the skip between the block dedicated for floats and a body text. The latter controls skip between text and a floats in the middle of a page. See the page 25 of the [`layouts`](https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf) package for more info

Comment: in your case, as all floats are placed between texts, you would need to set `\intextsep=0pt` to eliminate the extra space.

Comment: Hello, thank you @Celdor. But actually, the question was more about the fact that with the `caption` package, you go from a vertical space of 0.46 cm to 0.51 cm. If you put `\intextsep=0pt`, you will also notice a difference in spacing if you load the `caption` package or not. So why does loading `caption` change the spacing?

Comment: With all your settings, there is no difference between having and having not `caption` loaded on my side. Is your tex up to date? My log says the following: `LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> pre-release-0 (develop 2022-6-12 branch)` and `Package: caption 2022/03/01 v3.6b Customizing captions (AR)`, a few lines below: `Package: caption3 2022/03/17 v2.3b caption3 kernel (AR)`

Comment: @Celdor It's strange, I confirm that I have a (small) change in the vertical spacing (+0.05 cm) when loading the caption package. I tried with pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX. I have the LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1 version (it seems that the June 2022 version which is only a few days old is not yet distributed by Miktek). As for the packages, I have the same version as you. I tried it on Overleaf (TeX Live 2021) and it was the same.

Comment: You need `\captionsetup{strut=off}`. It's used in examples in `caption` package manual, but not yet documented, see https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/-/issues/71 .

Comment: BTW, it also seems like \caption can add \lineskip even with [skip=0pt].